# weaker upper bound of class number of O_k

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic, ideal-class-group

[image: statement[![][2]]
[image: statement and the proof[![][1]]

can anybody explain how the proof of this corollary is concluded?
i understood the proof right before the underlined sentence but still do not get how the argument before that leads to the underlined sentence. thank you. (uploaded 2 photos)

Comment: I think the idea is as follows. We have $j = q_1^{a_1} \cdots q_r^{a_r}$. An ideal of order $j$ is going to factor as a product of prime ideals above $q_1$ through $q_s$. In total, you expect at most $a_1 + \cdots + a_r$ such prime ideals. Moreover, how many primes are there above a given $q_i$? At most $n$, because $K$ has degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus in the worst-case scenario you have make $\sum_i a_i$ choices out of $n$ possibilities.

Comment: thank you very much. couldnt notice that the ideal I is factored into a product of prime ideals above q_i s.